# Extract Data from JSON URL

Tags: php, javascript, json

http://www.instamapper.com/api?action=getPositions&key=584014439054448247&num=10&format=json
is the url, which contains json data. I want to use that data and send SMS to a particular phone no if value of latitude and longitude(Extracted from JSON).
 Check constraints, we can use through php. But the main problem is How to extract data from JSON file?

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to give you the solution, so the below should be enough to get you started.

1. Read in the JSON data using [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
2. Parse the JSON string into a PHP object using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Your code should look something like this:

```
$url = "http://www.instamapper.com/api?action=getPositions&key=584014439054448247&num=10&format=json";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$jsonObj = json_decode($contents);
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
<?php

$jsonurl = "http://search.twitter.com/trends.json";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json);

foreach ( $json_output->trends as $trend )
{
    echo "{$trend->name}\n";
}
```